# Toggle Between two Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a Problem in making Some Toggle Effect with JQuery between Two divs . I am at very poor level on jQuery. and with that knowledge I failed to make to toggle between two divs .

**Current code in JS fiddle :**  **http://jsfiddle.net/WSCBu/**

I have Three Divs Class name Blue , Gray and orange . What I am trying to make is : when page loads Only two div Blue and Gray will Show and when I click the Text "Show" on Gray div The gray div will Hide and Orange Div will show . and When I click "Hide" text in Orange div this Orange div will Hide and again will show Gray div . May be it can be done with toggle function ? I am really not sure how . Hope for the Experts it  may easy one ! I will very thankful if anyone Show me the process .

here is **HTML**

```
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="gray">
  <p> Show --> </p>
</div>
<div class="orange">
  <p> -- Hide </p>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.blue{

height:100px;
width:250px;
background:#1ecae3;
float:left;
}
 .gray{

height:100px;
width:100px;
background:#eee;
float:left;    
 }

  .orange{
  height:100px;
  width:150px;
  background:#fdcb05;
  float:left;     
 }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you guessed, `toggle()` will do the job. When either `.gray` or `.orange` is clicked, we toggle the visibility of both:

```
$('.orange').hide();

$('.gray, .orange').on(
  'click',
  function() 
  {
    $('.gray, .orange').toggle()
  }
);
```

```js
$('.orange').hide();
$('.gray, .orange').on('click',
  function() {
    $('.gray, .orange').toggle()
  }
);
```

```css
.blue {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #1ecae3;
  float: left;
}

.gray {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
}

.orange {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #fdcb05;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="gray">
  <p>Show --></p>
</div>
<div class="orange">
  <p>-- Hide</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this one the best. I'd put `display:none` in the css for .orange, use .click(), make sure it is `.orange p` & `.gray p` to fit the requirements. I'd also make the cursor a pointer so that it is more obvious. ex: http://jsfiddle.net/N6eB6/3/

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/WSCBu/3/)

```
$('.orange').hide();
$('.gray p').click(function(){
    $('.gray').hide();
    $('.orange').show();
});
$('.orange p').click(function(){
    $('.gray').show();
    $('.orange').hide();
});
```

Shorter code with `.toggle()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/WSCBu/15/)

```
$('.orange').hide();
$('.gray p,.orange p').click(function(){
    $('.gray,.orange').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following js :

```
jQuery('.gray').click(function(){
   jQuery(this).hide();
   jQuery('.orange').show();     
});
jQuery('.orange').click(function(){
jQuery(this).hide();
   jQuery('.gray').show();    
});
```

Here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WSCBu/6/

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above answer:

```
$('.gray').click(function () {
    $(this).toggle();
    $('.orange').toggle();
});

$('.orange').click(function () {
    $(this).toggle();
    $('.gray').toggle();
});
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/WSCBu/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gray").click(function(){
$(".gray").toggle();
      $(".orange").show();
  });
$(".blue").click(function(){
$(".blue").toggle();
      $(".orange").show();

 });
$(".orange").click(function(){
    $(".blue").toggle();
    $(".gray").toggle();
    $(".orange").toggle();
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/WSCBu/5/)

Comment: Its working brilliantly ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.orange').hide();    
    $(".gray p").click(function(){
          $(".gray").hide();
          $(".orange").show();
    })
    $(".orange p").click(function(){
          $(".orange").hide();
          $(".gray").show();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class show to the two div and then you can use a toggle method. example http://jsfiddle.net/WSCBu/21/
shown here.

```
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="gray show" style="display:none";>
 <p> Show --> </p>
</div>
<div class="orange show">
 <p> -- Hide </p>
</div>

$(document).on('click','.show',function(){
  $('.show').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should as simple as the following code. Please forgive the code alignment. Answering it via my cell phone :)

```
<style>
.blue{

height:100px; width:250px; background:#1ecae3; float:left; } 

.gray{

height:100px; width:100px; background:#eee; float:left; }

.orange{ height:100px; width:150px; background:#fdcb05; float:left; display:none;}
</style>

 <div class="blue"></div>
 <div class="gray"> <p> Show --> </p> </div>
 <div class="orange"> <p> -- Hide </p> </div>

<script>
$(".gray p").click(function() {
$(".gray").hide();
$(".orange").show();
});

 $(".orange p").click(function() {
 $(".gray").show()
 $(".orange").hide();
 } );
 </script>
```