# How to Determine if Div is Toggled Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the example found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18110473/4847069, but I also want to check if a div is toggled or not. I'm not too familiar with Jquery, so I'm having trouble adding an if condition to the example provided. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(obj).is(':visible')` to determine if an object `obj` has been toggled as "visible."

Using the example in your linked post:

```js
$('.orange').hide();

$('.gray, .orange').on('click', function() {
  $('.gray, .orange').toggle();

  if($('.gray').is(':visible')) {
    $('#output').html('gray');
  }
  else {
    $('#output').html('orange');
  }      
});
```

```css
.blue{
  height:100px;
  width:250px;
  background:#1ecae3;
  float:left;
}
.gray{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:#eee;
  float:left;    
}

.orange{
  height:100px;
  width:150px;
  background:#fdcb05;
  float:left;     
}

#output {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="gray">
    <p> Show --> </p>
</div>
<div class="orange" >
    <p> -- Hide </p>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```