# How do I toggle 2 links (a tag) using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle 2 links (link1 and link2).

click link1 and it disables itself and enable link2 and vice-versa.

I got 2 issues:

1. link1 can still be clicked after clicking it. Same for link2.
2. on the 4 lines that has $("body"), I'm getting an error in the console. something about "TypeError: (intermediate value).apply is not a function" and it's pointing to a line in jquery.js

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/2srckcqg/9/)

```
<html
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setToggle("domestic");

        $('[id^="toggle_"]').on( "click", function() {
            var domInt = $(this).attr("id").replace("toggle_", "").toString();

            setToggle(domInt);
        });

        function setToggle(domInt) {
            domInt = domInt.toUpperCase();

            $("#clicked").append("domInt: " + domInt.toUpperCase() + " | ");
            if (domInt == "DOMESTIC") {
                $("body").off("click", "#toggle_domestic");
                $("body").on("click", "#toggle_international");

                $("#clicked").append("clicked domestic<br>");
            } else if (domInt == "INTERNATIONAL") {
                $("body").on("click", "#toggle_domestic");
                $("body").off("click", "#toggle_international");

                $("#clicked").append("clicked international<br>");
            }
        }
    });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="toggle_domestic">Domestic</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="toggle_international">International</a></p>
    <div id="clicked"></div>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle Between two Divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110320/toggle-between-two-divs)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click", "#toggle_domestic")/$("body").off("click", "#toggle_international");
```

is not actually disabling the link.You can disable a link using `css` properties or by returning `false`.

var domInt = $(this).attr("id").replace("toggle_", "").toString(); can be replaced by `$(this).text().trim()` if the requirement is to get the text

In this case use a common class(`anchorTag`) which target all the desired anchor tags. So on click of an anchor tag remove the `notActive` css class from all anchor tags and then this `nonActive` to the clicked anchor tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setToggle("domestic");

  $('.anchorTag').on("click", function() {
    $('.anchorTag').removeClass('notActive');
    $(this).addClass('notActive')
    var domInt = $(this).text().trim();
    setToggle(domInt);
  });

  function setToggle(domInt) {
    domInt = domInt.toUpperCase();

    $("#clicked").append("domInt: " + domInt.toUpperCase() + " | ");
    if (domInt == "DOMESTIC") {
      $("#clicked").append("clicked domestic<br>");
    } else if (domInt == "INTERNATIONAL") {
      $("#clicked").append("clicked international<br>");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.notActive {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="anchorTag" id="toggle_domestic">Domestic</a> |
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="anchorTag" id="toggle_international">International</a>
</p>
<div id="clicked"></div>
```