# Toggle between 2 divs when classes are variables

Tags: jquery

Trying to toggle between divs and I found this:

[Toggle Between Two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110320/toggle-between-two-divs)

Which works like a charm when the classes are static. I have a page where classes are variables:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var cShow = "client_"+id;
var cEdit = "clientChange_"+id;
$('.'+cShow,'.'+cEdit).toggle();
```

how can i encapsulate the whole identifier in quotes.

the solution above is:

```
 $('.class1,.class2').toggle();
```

mine becomes:

```
 $('class1','class2').toggle();
```

Comment: `$('.'+cShow+',.'+cEdit).toggle();`

Answer (score 2):

Your concatenation is slightly off, this should do the trick:

```
$('.'+cShow+',.'+cEdit).toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben! If you are not bound to old browsers support, or using e.g. Babel compiler, you can use string interpolation for more neat solution.

```js
$(`.${cShow},.${cEdit}`).toggle();
```

Or if you have an array of class names, just concatenate them with comma.

```js
const classes = ['user_123', 'active', 'golden-style', 'hello-world'];
const classesStr = classes.map(c => '.' + c).join(',');
console.log(classesStr);
```